# Trying to aggregate based on substring matches in mongodb 3.2

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Let's say my collection has documents with ExpName field and Rname field. Expname are all of the type - exp_1, exp_2 etc. Rname is a character string with 4 dashes for example. "As-34rt-d3r5-4453f-er4"

I need to aggregate based on experiment name and removing the text between the last two dashes. In the example I gave above that would be "As-34rt-d3r5"

question 1) how do i incorporate this in one table? 
question 2) i solved this in a dirty fashion for one exp, because it seemed like the number of characters was almost the same, so I could just take the first 13 characters which seemed like it was the the substring omitting the last two dashes. Is there a correct way to do this if the text was not so uniform?

```
db.getCollection('rest01').aggregate(
{$match : {ExpName : "exp_1"}},
{$group: {_id :"$ExpName",_id : {$substr : ["$RName", 0,13]}, total: { $sum:1 }}
})
```

Ideally I would like to have a result that says Expname, Rnamesubstring, count. This code snippet was for exp_1 one alone. Is it even possible to get it all in one result?

Comment: Clarity:  You want to group by BOTH the experiment and substring of rname?

Comment: yes. group by experiment and count the number of occurrences of a particular substring for each of the substrings

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you could do that:

```
db.getCollection('rest01').aggregate({
    $project: {
        "ExpName": 1,
        "splitRName": { $split: [ "$RName", "-" ] } // add an array with the constituents of your dash-delimited string id as a new field "splitRName"
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: { // our group id shall be made up of both...
            "ExpName": "$ExpName", // ...the "ExpName" field...
            "Rnamesubstring": { // and some parts of the "RName" field
                $concat:
                [
                    { $arrayElemAt: [ "$splitRName", 0 ] },
                    "-",
                    { $arrayElemAt: [ "$splitRName", 1 ] },
                    "-",
                    { $arrayElemAt: [ "$splitRName", 2 ] }
                ]
            }
        },
        total: { $sum: 1 }
    }
})
```

In case you want to do it in **MongoDB v3.2** (as stated in your comment), here is something that is not exactly pretty but works:

```
db.getCollection('rest01').aggregate({
    $group: {
        _id: { // our group id shall be made up of both...
            "ExpName": "$ExpName", // ...the "ExpName" field...
            "Rnamesubstring": {
                $substr:
                [
                    "$RName",
                    0,
                    {
                        $ifNull:
                        [
                            {
                                $arrayElemAt:
                                [{
                                    $filter: {
                                        input: {
                                            $map: {
                                                input: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30 /* add numbers as required */ ],
                                                as: "index",
                                                in: {
                                                    $cond: {
                                                        if: { $eq: [ "-", { $substr: [ "$RName", "$$index", 1 ] } ] }, // if the string we look at is a dash...
                                                        then: "$$index", // ...then let's remember it
                                                        else: null // ...otherwise ignore it
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },
                                        as: "item",
                                        cond: { $ne: [ null, "$$item" ] } // get rid of all null values
                                    }
                                },
                                2 ] // we want the position of the third dash in the string (only)
                            },
                            1000 // in case of a malformed RName (wrong number of dashes or completely missing) we want the entire substring
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        total: { $sum: 1 }
    }
})
```

**Update 2:** You seem to be having some data related issues as per your comments (so either missing RName values or improperly structured ones, i.e. without the required number of sections with dashes in between). I have updated the above statement for v3.2 to deal with these rows. You may want to find out, though, which rows actually cause this behaviour. They can be easily identified using the following statement:

```
db.getCollection('rest01').aggregate({
    $project: {
        _id: 1,
        RName: 1,
        "Rnamesubstring": {
            $arrayElemAt:
            [{
                $filter: {
                    input: {
                        $map: {
                            input: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30 /* add numbers as required */ ],
                            as: "index",
                            in: {
                                $cond: {
                                    if: { $eq: [ "-", { $substr: [ "$RName", "$$index", 1 ] } ] }, // if the string we look at is a dash...
                                    then: "$$index", // ...then let's remember it
                                    else: null // ...otherwise ignore it
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    as: "item",
                    cond: { $ne: [ null, "$$item" ] } // get rid of all null values
                }
            },
            2 ] // we want the position of the third dash in the string (only)
        }
    }
}, {
    $match: { "Rnamesubstring": { $exists:false } }
})
```

Comment: Ha!  I was JUST about to post the same thing!

Comment: Good man. And I'm sorry for being faster this time - I will go to bed soon so it's your turn again. ;)

Comment: i got this eroor message when i tried to run it! "Error:
Assert: command failed: {
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$addFields'",
 "code" : 16436
} : aggregate failed
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:16:14
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:370:5
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1319:5
@(shell):1:1"

Comment: I guess that option is only present in 3.4? Is there an equivalent in 3.2? I am not seeing anything out there..

Comment: @user1775614: I updated the code for v3.2 compliance. Couldn't test, though, since I'm away from my equipment...

Comment: It looks like there is an error with split - not sure what is going on... "Error:
Assert: command failed: { "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "invalid operator '$split'", "code" : 15999 } : aggregate failed
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:16:14
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:370:5
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1319:5
@(shell):1:1"

Comment: Damn, yes, the documentation says "New in version 3.4."

Comment: Any other ideas?

Comment: @user1775614; I'll give it some thought but if it's possible it won't be pretty... So upgrading MongoDB would certainly be a good idea. Anyway, as an alternative you could also capture your RName data already in a chunked fashion as an array of all the individual items. Or you could as well do the string operations on the client side after retrieving the full values from MongoDB.

Comment: @user1775614: Wow, it can actually be done in v3.2 - check the updated post.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, but I am still getting an error :(. \\"Error:
Assert: command failed: {
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "$substr:  length must be a numeric type (is BSON type EOO)",
 "code" : 16035
} : aggregate failed
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:16:14
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:370:5
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1319:5
@(shell):1:1"

Comment: This would seem to indicate that you don't have uniformely structured  data, e.g. an RName with less than three dashes in it or entries without an RName.

Comment: Maybe its timet o update to 3.4 i guess. This will not be an issue with split will it?

Comment: @user1775614: Updating to the latest version is certainly a good idea. In a few days/weeks there should be the new v3.6 which you might want to consider as a good target. Mind you, the 3.2 version I posted should work. You will just need to isolate the records that cause problems. I'll add a statement for that in a couple of seconds.